# NetBeans Make Command when using MinGW

Tags: c++, netbeans, makefile, mingw

I'm trying to use NetBean to program C++, I have followed each of the
commands found here:
https://netbeans.org/community/releases/68/cpp-setup-instructions.html#compilers_windows

However, I am having trouble with the make command option in netbeans. I have set the base directory o M:\c++\bin, where I have MinGW installed, and I have the make command set to M:\MinSYS\bin\make.exe, but when trying to build a simple program, netbeans produces the following error:

```
"/M/c++/MinSYS/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/m/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
"/M/c++/MinSYS/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/m/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
make.exe[2]: mkdir: Command not found
make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o] Error 127
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/m/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/m/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

I have tried changing the make command to anything with make in it, but neither get anywhere, any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: The problem doesn't have anything to do with how you invoke make, per se; the error message is pretty clear I think: `mkdir: Command not found`  It cannot find the `mkdir` command that your makefile is trying to invoke.  It sounds like an environment or configuration issue.

Comment: Your answer is here: http://forums.netbeans.org/topic38061.html

Answer (score 9):

When using MinGW it is said that mingw make is not supported, so install MSYS make utility from MinGW and update in build tools make command as shown in below picture, hope it helps.

[Installation of MSYS make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ5w1.png)

[Update make command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRpRn.png)

Comment: Works for me on Windows 7 / Netbeans 8.2

Comment: Works for me on Windows 10 / Netbeans 8.2 /  64 bit

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem. Saw the answer on another post and it fixed the issue. Make sure to restart NetBeans after doing the following:

Right click on My Computer and select properties. Click Advanced System Settings.System Properties dialog box will open. click Environmental Variables. Edit PATH variable and add C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin